# Use spread props with additional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I append another property?  I have a react component where someone has passed in ...props and I want to append on an extra prop

```
 <AccountsStatus {...props} />
```

Comment: `{ ...props, extraProp: someValue }`?

Comment: yea it works, I tried that before posting this and was getting an error but it's fine.

Comment: Should I post this as answer?

Answer (score 24):

Bear in mind that the order in which you pass your props will determine which value is passed through to that component. This applies if there are two keys with the same name.

**For example:**

```
<AccountsStatus extraProp={extraValue} {...props} />
```

and

```
<AccountsStatus {...props} extraProp={extraValue} />
```

look the same, but in the first example, if you were spreading your `props` object which contained an `extraProp` key, it would overwrite the `extraProp` value you pass before it.

Comment: This is super helpful, and was exactly the info I was looking for. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 11):

Just add in the sequence:

```
<AccountsStatus {...props} otherProp={true} />
```

Or you can clone props, add the other prop to the clone, and then do:

```
<AccountsStatus {...newProps} />
```

But I wouldn't recommend on doing that, you'd nee a lib to clone the object.

Comment: If there's already a value for `otherProp` inside `props` you will have to use the second method, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LuanNico, no everything that comes after the spread should take precedence. Properties are "applied" in order.

Comment: That's good to know, @FelixKling. I was unsure about this behavior. Thanks :))

Answer (score 3):

More concise approach to do this is based on using [an object spread operator](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread):

```
<AccountsStatus {...{...props, extraProp: extraValue}} />
```

To be able to use it, you'll need to configure Babel to use [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin.

Comment: I don't think that works? React JSX spread doesn't allow adding an extra prop like that. You would have to construct the Object with a spread, add the extra prop, then spread that object into the AccountStatus props.
`<AccountStatus {...{ ...props, extraProp: extraValue }} />`.
Another way is to do `<AccountStatus {...props} extraProp={extraValue} />`. They have the same result but the second method doesn't require object spread. Keep in mind it's not just adding a prop, it can override an existing prop too.

Comment: As of ES2018, this plugin is part of Babel by default so no extra configuration is required. Great one-liner solution. More info [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread).

Answer (score 0):

Just send the prop above the spread operator:

```
<AccountsStatus
    otherProp={otherPropValue}
    {...props}
/>
```

Keep in mind to always specify it above the spread props. If you're passing the prop with same name in props, you probably want to override it.
You can read more on props in [this article](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic), it's covering a lot of ways on how certain types of props are passed.